# How to "update" the _id column in SQLite Database Browser

Tags: sqlite

The _id column in my database is an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, so it is an auto-incrementing column.
The problem is that now I deleted a row, and the column didn't update the auto-incrementing number.

Is there a way to make the _id column update, so there wouldn't be holes in the sequence?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why? That's not how the id numbers are supposed to work. What is the problem you're trying to solve with the holes filled?

Comment: I need no holes in the progression because I'm using that database with an app that search for a random _id number, and if it don't find that _id number, the app crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is not how it is intended to be used. Don't mess with the primary key! There will be gapes. The `id` is just a unique identifier.

If you need a rank then you can do that

```
select t.*, @rank := @rank + 1 as gapless_rank
from your_table t
cross join (select @rank := 0) r
order by id
```

Comment: I think rank() function is wtg nowdays. This did not work for me anymore

Answer (score 0):

To get the `n`th ID from the table, use a query like this:

```
SELECT _id
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY _id
LIMIT 1
OFFSET n-1
```